# How to specify "Aunt", "Uncle", "Cousin" relative to father or mother, in German?

Tags: translation, vocabulary

If we would specify "Onkel", "Tante" or "Cousin(e)" related through the mother's side of the family, can we use:

> mein mütterlicher Onkel
>   meine mütterliche Tante
>   meine mütterliche Cousine

because "Onkel", for example, may mean "brother of mother or father".

Is that correct for Germans?

Answer (score 6):

You'd normally use "mütterlicherseits" or "väterlicherseits".

Answer (score 5):

A maternal uncle is called “Onkel mütterlicherseits” in German. “Mütterlicher Onkel” would refer to a motherly uncle.

Answer (score 2):

`Onkel` may even specify the husband of your father's or mother's sister (or with a liberal view: male significant other of your father's or mother's sibling).